# Send email to Outlook that includes an html form submit

Tags: html, forms, outlook

I am writing a Java application that generates an email including an html form that the recipient can submit (the HTTP request performed by the submit executes is dynamically constructed by the sending application).

This works fine in gmail but since Outlook doesn't support HTML tags "form" or "button", it doesn't work in Outlook.

All of our users are using Outlook so if I could create a plugin in Outlook which interpreted/rendered the content of the received email then this could be a solution.

Does anything like this exist?  The only thing I can find is ways of creating email templates that can be used when the email is initiated from within Outlook, not the other way round.

Comment: To add something like this sounds very complicated, if it's possible at all. Wouldn't it be waaaay easier to just link to a web form online?

Comment: Alternative idea: a PDF with a form that posts/E-Mails? Never done that, though, so no idea how workable it is. https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/form-submit-e-mail-demystified

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Pekka..at least confirming my suspicion there is no easy way of doing it :)